# Position operator

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, physics, intuition, mathematical-physics

I'm learning about unbounded operator densely defined on Hilbert spaces from "Reed & Simon, Functional Analysis".

The first example was the *position operator*, which is defined as follows.

Let $D(T) = \{ \varphi \in L^2(\mathbb R) : \int_\mathbb R x^2|\varphi(x)|^2 {\rm d}x < \infty \}$ and $T\colon D(T)\to L^2(\mathbb R)$ be given by $T\varphi(x) = x\varphi(x)$.

Well, the domain $D(T)$ of $T$ that was chosen is the largest one for which the range of $T$ is in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

I am wondering: Why such operator is called *position* operator? What is its meaning for physicists? What is the intuition in defining such operator like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $|\phi|^2$ can be interpreted as the probability density that a particle described by the function $\phi$ is a t position $x\in\mathbb{R}$ in one dimension, and thus the expected value for the position is $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x|\phi(x)|^2dx$ but this doesn´t explain the square...

Comment: @Melech what is the connection between the operator $T\varphi(x)=x\varphi(x)$ and the expected value of the position?

Comment: The expected measure of position for a system in state $\psi$ is $\langle T\psi,\psi\rangle$. $\psi$ is a unit vector. The expected value is guaranteed to be close to $x$ if $\psi$ is concentrated near $x$. The limiting case is where $\psi \approx \delta_x$, where $\delta_x$ is a Dirac delta at $x$. An approximate $\delta_x$ is very nearly an eigenfunction of $T$ with eigenvalue $x$, which represents something with a definite position at $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answers were already given in the comments but I will try to elaborate: In (non-relativistic single-particle) quantum mechanics, the *state* of a particle is modeled by a *wave-function* $\psi$. Typically these functions are modeled by $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{C}^k)$, that is complex vector valued and square integrable functions over the euclidean $d$-space (for physics it is $d=1,2,3$).

The name 'wave-function' originates from the fact that we will typically model a particles evolution by some wave equation, namely a *Schrödinger equation*
$$i \partial_t \psi(t) = H\psi(t) \qquad\text{for}\qquad \psi\colon\mathbb{R}\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{C}^k),$$
where $H\colon \mathcal{D}(H) \subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{C}^k)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{C}^k)$ is some self-adjoint but possibly unbounded linear operator.

Now, with the basic setting presented, we state a *physical interpretation* of a wave function: $|\psi(t,x)|^2$ is proportional to the probability of measuring the particle at position $x$. Consequently, $\int_{\mathbb{R^d}} x |\psi(t,x)|^2 \mathrm{d}{x} = \langle\psi,T\psi\rangle_{L^2}$ is the *mean position* of the particle at time $t$. For this reason, we refer to $T$ as the position operator.

**Further remarks:** There are various subtleties around choosing the right model-space and 'giving physical interpretation'. One could also choose wave functions to 'live over momentum space' instead of 'position space' (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space)). In this case, the multiplication operator as given by yourself would be the *momentum operator*. In the end, this boils down to representing a quantum mechanical state in different eigen-basis of different self-adjoint operators, which in our above case was simply the position operator: Given a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ equipped with a self-adjoint (let's assume cyclic) operator $T$, we find an isometry $U\colon \mathcal{H} \to L^2(\sigma(T))$, such that $U T U^\ast$ acts as a multiplication operator on $L^2(\sigma(T))$. Hence, I could have also answered your question as: It is called the position operator, since we decided to model our wave-functions as $L^2$-functions over the spectrum the position operator :).

Comment: Nice! (+1) Thanks for your answer. I think I'm getting used to these ideas